# How to select sequence bytes in IDA Pro Hex View?

Tags: ida

As you see below gif, I can't select the sequence bytes what I want, the selections range is a rectagle, it's against humanity. How can I select sequence bytes?

[image]

Annotated variant of the above (obtained from IDA 8.2.221215):

[image: Annotated clip showing the issue arising from only being able to select rectangular ranges]

Comment: I edited your question to add another GIF which makes the issue you seem to be referring to more obvious.

Comment: @0xC0000022L It's unbelievable that a software with such poor basic functions can be sold so expensive.

Comment: Hmm, IDA is not a good hex editor, agreed, but the result in a hex editor such a 010 Editor is also often suboptimal when the selected range doesn't end exactly at the same boundaries as the lines. So I'm not sure I totally agree with your assessment; even though I certainly would expect this to be fixed eventually. Have you contacted Hex-Rays?

Comment: @0xC0000022L No, I use Freeware version, I don't think they'll pay me any attention.

Comment: Actually I think they might, since it also affects paying customers. Eventually I or another paying customer will probably get in touch with them unless Igor raises this internally already.

Comment: @0xC0000022L Ha, hopefully in the future they will be able to sell the kernel/core separately that will provide an API for users to write their own GUI.

Comment: what would you want to do with the selection? maybe there's a better way

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky Extract 16-bytes GUID.

Comment: ok i added an answer with ALT+L but you mean if you need to select from 8th byte t0 24th byte it becomes impossible :( it skips the columns and becomes rectangle selection yes it appears to be come kind of kink

Comment: I also had this question long ago; thanks for bringing this question up ! (I never asked it) appreciating it

Answer (score 1):

Currently (as of 8.2), the selection in Hex View is fixed to rectangular shape (I *think* it was done to sidestep the issue of the text block to the side), so the answer to the question as asked is "it's impossible".

For extracting contiguous data it may be more convenient to use IDA View instead of the Hex View. You can use Export Data (<kbd>Shift-E</kbd>) to get the selection in different formats, including as a structure instance (if you have a struct defined):

https://hex-rays.com/blog/igors-tip-of-the-week-39-export-data/

Comment: You're right. But this feature is hidden a bit deep. It should appear inside right click context menu when I selected data in IDA View. :)

Comment: I don't know if I should accept this as an answer because while it addresses my needs, but it doesn't match the original question.

Comment: the context menu is already very crowded, adding all possible actions to it would not fit most monitors.